# The struct that is stored to my file isn't being Overwritten ( C )

Tags: c, file, struct, overwrite

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct batch
{
  int month;
  int day;
  int qty;
  float item_cost;
  int batch_num;
} BATCH;

struct stock
{
  char item_name[50];
  int t_qty;
  float t_item_cost;
  int item_code;
  BATCH batch[10];
  int last_batch_num;
  float price_for_one;
  float price;
};

int main()
{
   FILE *filepointer;
   filepointer = fopen("stocklist.txt", "r+");

   struct stock loop;

   while(fread(&loop, sizeof(struct stock), 1, filepointer))
   {
       printf("%s\n", loop.item_name);
       strcpy(loop.item_name, "Jerb");
       printf("%s\n", loop.item_name);

       fwrite(&loop, sizeof(struct stock), 1, filepointer);
    }
}
```

There is a text file which has in an item_name which is Huggies, so every time I run the program it should change the name of Huggies to "Jerb" but it seems that it isn't having any effect on the file and the old item_name stays in the same in the file.

I would have thought that if I used the "r+" mode it would overwrite this data in the file but it isn't.

Help please!!

Comment: Did you check the file-size? You don't rewind, how would the record be overwritten?

Comment: Have you considered padding your struct? It isn't aligned, so the compiler will pad it.

Comment: I think the "However.." statement in [the description of the extended open modes of `fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) (such as your `r+` does), are probably worth a second (or first) look.

Comment: There is serious problem with you code. You are editing and reading your file at the same time, and that too whole 276 bytes?

Comment: Try and replace sizeof(struct stock) with 5 everywhere for testing

Comment: @user64322 I can't understand your comments; what does "and that too whole 276 bytes?" mean? and also, do you mean "replace sizeof(struct)"?

Comment: Try this   
    "while(fread(&loop, 5, 1, filepointer))"

Comment: @user64322 it loops multiple times and prints out garbage but doesn't change the contents of the file.

Comment: When I do rewind though it does change the contents but it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: It will go in infinite loop cause you are writing in your file and then reading again than again writing again reading...

Comment: The first thing I would do is check that filepointer is not NULL after you try to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing fflush() inside the loop and fclose before exiting. When fwrite() is called, the output is written to a buffer until 4kb of data is generated and flushed to the file only when it reaches 4kb or when fflush/fclose is called.